# How can I compile Python code with only the necessary parts of a module?

Tags: python, compilation, pyinstaller, auto-py-to-exe, nuitka

How can I compile Python code with only the required parts or functions from a module, such as including **Keras from TensorFlow** but not the whole TensorFlow library? I have tried using **PyInstaller and Nuitka**, but they include the whole TensorFlow library, **which is about 1GB**, as well as NumPy and Matplotlib. My application is AINeuralNetwork-based, but after compiling it, the resulting application is a whole new application with a **massive size**. Is there any way to produce optimized binaries from Python that only include the necessary parts of a module?
Here is an example-

```
# Importing only the required functions from a module
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout

# Using the imported functions
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
```

here only want the selected module to compile like Dense and Dropout not the whole **Tensorflow Library**.
Things I tried to reduce the final output size-

1. Virtual Env with only selected package
2. Cx_freeze
3. Nuitka
4. Pyinstaller
5. Numpy Vanilla libraries

But i want pure compiled version of my python program which is compiled in way that it automatically contain the required code from library not the whole library?

Comment: i don't even think this is possible in principle. certainly, anything that could accomplish this would rely on various heuristics. I've never heard of anything that attempts to.

Comment: does that means that no matter hard i try i can't get size less than gb when using tensorflow functions? even if its just linear regression or just print matrix?

Comment: Which parts of the tensorflow package can you safely remove without breaking it?

Comment: I don't know why are you asking but my question is how can i decrease the size of python built program when using tensorflow ? cause a simple program which only add some matrix  A and B the final size of program increases more than 1gb in size.